# Automating Mastermap update in Oracle Spatial?

Tags: open-source-gis, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap, oracle-spatial

I've been set a challenge which is a bit out of my comfort zone. I'm an esri developer trying to break into the open source world.

I've been asked to automate the update of some oracle SDO datasets. I have a boundaries dataset (X) that needs to match topologically with OS Mastermap data. At the moment, the Mastermap update is a manual process (disk in the post!). If a boundary in the OS data is updated e.g a field is reduced as a result of a new road, the same field in dataset X needs to be updated accordingly. At first, I'm expected to flag up any changes that will need to be made to dataset X. Eventually, dataset X will be updated automatically. I also need to store the changes made for audit purposes. I've been challenged to achive the above with an open source stack.

My initial thoughts are that a workflow could look like – download update -> import dataset -> select all new and updated toids in OS dataset -> some kind of spatial query to identify effected features in dataset x-> export selected features to archive -> edit selected to snap to new OS boundaries.

Has anyone attempted something similar? What tooling would the community recommend?

Comment: Do you want to keep using oracle spatial or not (a bit unclear whether storing the data is part of the "open source stack")?

Comment: Hi johanvdw.Yes I do need to keep all data in SDO and georaster formats...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the TOID in OS MASTERMAP with the Date fields of MASTERMAP to link the objects.

We have TOIDS from MASTERMAP assigned to other datasets so that the geometry is always taken from MASTERMAP until the TOID is ended in MASTERMAP and then the data is flagged in an audit table to say that there is no longer any data for this and we need to look at it.

We either update the SDO_GEOMETRY column in the dataset with that from MASTERMAP when we receive the MASTERMAP update, or depending on the dataset size create a view linked using the toid and dates.

This can then be added to a procedure along with the import of MASTERMAP data depending on how you receive it (ours is change only via FTP).